# How to compile Node.js with figlet module from pkg?

Tags: node.js, compiler-errors, exe

After compiling via pkg and running the .exe, I got the error:

```
(node:17672) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: File 'C:\**\mytestapp\node_modules\figlet\fonts\Ghost.flf' was not included into executable at compilation stage. Please recompile adding it as asset or script.
```

**my index.js and package.json:** https://pastebin.com/vL4nZcZW

I tried to add the entire figlet module to the asset, reinstall it and pkg, but this did not work. I tried to compile with only one require. What am I doing wrong?